# Display a range of cells based on input from a drop down

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save space on a worksheet that has a list of courses in the A column and dates in consecutive columns starting at AB. 
Under the courses I have a list of people in freeze frame, with cells filled to indicate whether they are available
I currently am annotating what dates the course is held by filling the cells under the date columns.  What I would like to do is have a drop down menu with the course names, which would show the corresponding filled cells to the right.
It seems like this should be possible, but I haven't been able to find code that really does what I want it to.

Comment: I don't think you need VBA for this. If I understand you correctly, you could use a `Data Validation List` to get your course names in the drop down. Then you can use either / or  `Vlookup`, `Offset`, `Match` or `Index` functions to get the cells to the right. It really depends on how your data is set up.

Comment: Agree with Scott as well, +1 from me.

Comment: Agreed. That is the way that I finally made it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that you want to hide all the rows, probably should lock them to make sure data is changed, and then insert a drop down list, listbox, combobox or whatever you prefer.  Then you can populate the list by doing something similar to this...

```
   For Each cell in Worksheet("").Range("Your Range Here")
         ComboBox1.Add(cell)
   Next
```

or...

```
   ComboBox1.AddRange("Your Range Here")
```

You should then use the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged (Or Similar) Event to identify which course is currently selected like...

```
   If e.SelectedIndex = "Some Course" Then
       ' Unhide Proper Rows/Columns
   End If
```

Don't forget to check for '-1' (Nothing is selected)

```
   If e.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
```

If you need a more specific answer, let me know, I had a tough time following where the data is in the worksheet, you said 'Consecutive Columns", which I implied meant, there is a Course in Colunmn A of a row, followed by several dates in the same row until Column AB.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It turns out that VLOOKUP was the right answer for this problem. I just needed to put values in the cells instead of just filling/higlighting them and then use conditional formatting to get the results I wanted.  Thanks for all of your answers.